# Redirect old domain to new domain with different URL structure NGINX

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

As the title says I want to redirect a domain to another domain with different URL structure. for example, domain A have URL like this

```
domainA.com/files/ghgjhgjhgytuyjghjhhg
```

Domain B has the same file with another url

```
domainB.com/box/ghgjhgjhgytuyjghjhhg
```

I tested using this rewrite rule, but all redirected URL ended with 404 not found error on new domain.

```
rewrite ^ https://www.domainB.com$request_uri? permanent;
```

Please help me how can redirect domain A to DomainB.

Comment: Quick suggestion is while testing you should be using temporary redirects rather than permanent. You're going to need to write a regular expression to do this transform. I'm not great at those, I work them out by reading tutorials and using a site like https://regex101.com/

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/files(.*)$ https://example.com/box$1;`